# Google Play Films: Transparent play image

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport, android-developer-api

Where can I find a transparent play button image like in play films' store over the trailer? Please check out the link for the image.

[Google Play Films' Store Image](http://postimg.org/image/vuo87b7vr/)

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This image seems simple so you can draw it by yourself using [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/download/) and save it as an .SVG file. After you're done you can export it as a semi-transparent .PNG in the desired resolution that can be imported into any Android project.